# Select first row from a list that have multiple row for each identifier

Tags: sql, hadoop, hiveql

I have the following data:

| Column_A | Column_B |
| --- | --- |
| 123456 | 678 |
| 123456 | 999 |

I would like to achieve the following result:

| Column_A | Column_B |
| --- | --- |
| 123456 | 999 |

Here's my code:

```
SELECT COLUMN_A, MAX(COLUMN_B) FROM TABLE;
```

Is there any alternative to achieve the result from using **max(Column_B)** function? I can't use the **max()** function because it was disabled in the database that I'm working with. Thank you in advance!

Comment: how can max be disabled? is that even possible?

Comment: sort by column B, desc and return max of 1 record? - i.e. `WHERE row <= 1
ORDER BY column_b desc` or something like that?

Comment: Hi drum, I'm getting this message "Not yet supported place for UDAF 'max'", not sure why. Hi blurfus, thanks for your feedback, the working solution please see the answer section. Thanks a lot for all the replied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative could be to use `ROW_NUMBER()`, `ORDER BY` and `GROUP BY` statements together in addition to a subquery, like this:

```sql
SELECT column_a, column_b
FROM(
 SELECT column_a, column_b, row_number() over (partition by column_a order by column_b desc) as rownum
 FROM table
)
WHERE rownum=1;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! The solution provide doesn't work in the environment that I worked with, so I split your SQL into 2 part and it works!